# AXIS2 Webservice client SOAP envelope error

Tags: java, xml, web-services, apache-axis, axiom

I have problem with our webservice client. I used to send data to webservice with no problem, but we migrated from Geronimo to Weblogic, and ws client stopped to work. I have investigated data, which are being sent:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header><ns1:loginData xmlns:ns1="http://xxxxxx.xx/xxx/xx/xxxx/webservice/xxxxxx/auction/types" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0"><ns1:anonymous>false</ns1:anonymous></ns1:loginData></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><ns1:offersSend xmlns:ns1="http://xxxxxx.xx/xxx/xx/xxxx/webservice/xxxxxx/auction/types"><ns1:http://xxxxxx.xx/xxx/xx/xxxx/webservice/etrace/auction/types>......
```

http://xxxxxx.xx/xxx/xx/xxxx/webservice/xxxxxx/auction/types>

Returned error message is:

```
soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode><faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: &lt;Line 1, Column 426&gt;: XML-20201: (Fatal Error) Expected name instead of :.</faultstring><detail><ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">xxxx.xxxxxx.xxx</ns1:hostname></detail>
```

I'm curious what is wrong, is it some AXIS configuration? What are possibilities to get it working?

**EDIT:**
I have found that the problem lies in this part:

```
<ns1:http://xxxxxx.xx/xxx/xx/xxxx/webservice/etrace/auction/types>
```

Old working XML looked like this:

```
<ns1:entityData>
```

But how is it possible, that AXIS is doing call completely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely caused by [AXIOM-421](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIOM-421). The issue occurs with certain Axiom versions in combination with certain StAX implementations. Probably after migrating from Geronimo to Weblogic, the StAX implementation that is used by the application is different.

The solution is either to upgrade to a newer Axiom version or to add Woodstox to your application so that it is used instead of Weblogic's StAX implementation.